# Finitely additive "measure" that is not upper-continuous

Tags: analysis, measure-theory

Let $X$ be a set and $\mathcal{A}\subset 2^X$ an algebra of subsets (i.e closed under finite intersection, union and complements) containing $\emptyset$.  Suppose $$\mu: \mathcal{A}\rightarrow [0,1]$$

is finitely additive (for disjoint sets) with $\mu(X)=1$.  Is it possible that for a nested family $A_1 \supset A_2 \supset... $ of elements of $\mathcal{A}$ with $\cap_n A_n =\emptyset$, we have $\lim_n\mu(A_n)\neq 0$?

Remark:  I'm pretty sure there is such a measure.  The reason is that the hypothesis of upper-continuity is part of a well-known extension theorem used to extend $\mu$ to the $\sigma$ algebra generated by $\mathcal{A}$.

Comment: Which extension procedure is that? Also yes, you're right. There should be such a measure. The limit of the measure converges to zero if and only if the measure is countably additive.

Comment: It says that if $\mu$ and $\mathcal{A}$ are as above, and if the measure of a nested intersection is always the limit of the measures, then there exists a measure on the sigma algebra generated by $\mathcal{A}$ which agrees with $\mu$ on $\mathcal{A}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $X=\mathbb N$ and let $\mathcal A=2^\mathbb N.$ Let $\mathcal U$ be a nonprincipal [ultrafilter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultrafilter) on $\mathbb N$ (this requires the axiom of choice). Define $\mu:\mathcal A\to\{0,1\}$ by setting $\mu(A)=1$ for $A\in\mathcal U$ and $\mu(A)=0$ for $A\notin\mathcal U.$ Then $\mu$ is a finitely additive probability measure, and $\mu(A)=0$ for all finite $A.$ Let $A_n=\{n,n+1,n+2,\dots\}$; then $A_1\supset A_2\supset A_3\supset\cdots$ and $\bigcap_n A_n=\emptyset$ and $\lim_n\mu(A_n)=1.$

Comment: *Very* interesting. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking for looks like the class of [purely finitely additive measures](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1952-072-01/S0002-9947-1952-0045194-X/S0002-9947-1952-0045194-X.pdf).

Comment: Interesting paper. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

On $\mathbb{N}$, let $\mathcal{A}$ be the collection of finite or cofinite sets. Define $\mu$ to be $0$ on finite sets and $1$ on cofinite sets. This is essentially the same example that bof gave. I'm not sure why you need ultrafilters.